# Executing the code after run method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a method in class A which creates a thread and invokes the run method in class B. I have a list in class B that is updated in run method of class B and I need to access that in class A after the run method returns. I have given the sample code below.

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List l = null;

        B obj = new B();
        Thread T = new Thread(obj);
        T.start();

        l = obj.getList();
        // do something with l    
    }
}

class B implements Runnable {

    List l;

    void run() {
        l = doSomething();    
    }

    public List getList() {
        return List l;
    }
}
```

Now I am getting null when i get the list value `l = obj.getList();` which is in the class A. The line `l = obj.getList();` in class A is immediately gets called before it gets updated by the run method. How to make the main thread wait and display the correct value after the thread T returns. Kindly suggest?

Comment: Sweet pseudo for such simple code.

Comment: Have a look at the ``Future<V>`` interface.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained ;)

Comment: I would add Callable<V> along with Future<V> might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the other suggestions might be useful, too. The most simple solution would be to wait for the thread to end.

```
T.start();
T.join();

l = obj.getList();
```

Comment: +1 If the main thread needs to _wait_ for the value then `join()` is the best solution, not just the more simple.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, I see no reason to even spawn the thread in the first place.

Instead of

```
B obj = new B();
Thread T = new Thread(obj);
T.start();
```

You could do:

```
new B().run();
```

Using join is more useful when you do something in between the start and join.

```
T.start();
//do some other work here
T.join();
```